# Google geolocation get same data in different languages

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geolocation

I am using following code from Googles API in a Register/login script, to get the address of the user:

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  street_number: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
  country: 'long_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  
  /*document.getElementById('place_id').value = place.place_id;
  document.getElementById('place_id').disabled = false;*/

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    /*document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;*/
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]
```

```html
<label class="tooltip" for="autocomplete">Hier Adresse eingeben:</label>
         <input type="text" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Adresse hier eingeben" onFocus="geolocate()" />
                <label for="street_number">Strasse / Hausnummer:</label>
                <input type="text"  name="form_street" id="route" readonly       placeholder="Strasse wird automatisch ausgefüllt" />
                <input type="text"  name="form_street_number" id="street_number" readonly />
                <label  for="locality">PLZ / Stadt:</label>
                <input type="text"  name="form_postal_code" id="postal_code" readonly placeholder="PLZ autom. ausgefüllt" />
                <input type="text"  name="form_town" id="locality" readonly  placeholder="Ort wird automatisch ausgefüllt" />
                <label  for="administrative_area_level_1">Bundesland:</label>
                <input type="text"  name="form_state" id="administrative_area_level_1" readonly placeholder="Bundesland wird automatisch ausgefüllt" />
                <label for="postal_code">Land:</label>
                <input type="text" name="form_country" id="country" readonly placeholder="Land wird automatisch ausgefüllt" />
```

Everything works fine. My Question: Is there a possibility to get country, state, town in other languages at the same time? I want to put it in hidden fields and store it in database. I cant put my api key into the code snippet so it wont work here, but at home it works fine.

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't localize the API to more than one language at a time.  You might be able, once you submit, to use the Geocoding service, localized to the other language, on the server side to look up the place id returned by the autocomplete search, and then store that address info.